# Reputation audit page ("sitename.com/reputation") says it requires 10 reputation to view when not logged in?

Tags: bug, reputation, privileges, error-message, reputation-audit

When I add `/reputation` at the end of any site name for a **community I haven't joined**, it says I need 10 reputation to see the page. But I can see my reputation history through `/reputation` for communities that I've joined but only have 1 reputation in.

Screenshot for reference:

[image: Can see the reputation history with one reputation]

For example, I haven't joined the Academia community yet. When I use https://academia.stackexchange.com/reputation I get this error page:

> **This page requires more privileges**
>
> ---
>
> The page you're trying to visit requires the privilege “[Answer protected questions](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/new-user).”
>
> You receive additional privileges on Academia Stack Exchange by earning more [reputation](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) through participation on the site. When you have earned at least 10 reputation, you will receive the “answer protected questions” privilege and will be allowed to view this page.
>
> Visit the [privileges page](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) to learn more about the privileges you can earn.

If the reputation audit can be viewed by users with 1 reputation, then why does it say it requires 10 reputation?

If the 10-reputation restriction needs to be shown for some reason, can be the privilege be renamed to "remove new user restrictions" instead of "Answer protected questions"?

> The page you're trying to visit requires the privilege “[Answer protected questions](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/new-user).”

Instead of the above, it would be more meaningful to show:

> The page you're trying to visit requires the privilege “[remove new user restrictions](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/new-user).”

Comment: This is most likely a bug, the page should redirect to the login page, same way [edit profile link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current) is doing when viewed while not logged in.

Comment: Try incognito: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Q6OE.png

Comment: @ShadowWizard You are correct.

Comment: And also, if not redirecting to login, it should throw 404 error. (the /reputation page)